# Spring Boot: 2 in-memory databases, first one initialized by flyway, second manually

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2, flyway, in-memory-database

I have two `H2` databases in my Spring boot application. Each of these databases is responsible for persistence of different entities.

The first one is initialized by `Flyway` which works fine, but now I need to initialize the other H2 database. I think I have found out that it is impossible to initialize multiple databases with Flyway. So I am trying to manually import my `schema.sql` and `data.sql` files

This is what I have till now:
Two separate DatasourceConfig files:

The first data source config (Notice how this datasource is configured to be primary):

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"prod","test"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "tracker.repository.h2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "h2TransactionManager")
public class PrivateH2DatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(h2DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"tracker.domain.h2"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("h2.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("h2.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("h2.datasource.data-username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("h2.datasource.data-password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(h2EntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Second H2 datasource config file:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "tracker.repository.wmx",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "wmxH2EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "wmxH2TransactionManager")
public class WmxH2DatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean wmxH2EntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(wmxH2DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"tracker.domain.wmx"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource wmxH2DataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("test.h2.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("test.h2.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("test.h2.datasource.data-username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("test.h2.datasource.data-password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager wmxH2TransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(wmxH2EntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Then I have application.properties:

```
#can be over ridden by run arguments
spring.profiles.active=test

flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true


## H2
h2.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/deliverytracker.h2
h2.datasource.data-username=x
h2.datasource.data-password=xxx


## H2 WMX (Test environment)
test.h2.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
test.h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/wmx_test.h2
test.h2.datasource.data-username=x
test.h2.datasource.data-password=xxx
test.h2.datasource.initialize=true
test.h2.datasource.data=classpath:schema-test.sql,classpath:data-test.sql
```

and the last line is how I have been trying to import the sql scripts in the correct database, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The first (non-primary) database file is created but it is empty.